# キッチンタイマーで音を鳴らす

Tags: javascript

設定した時間後にアラート画面を出すサンプルコードは見つかりましたが、音を鳴らすにはどのようにコードを書き換えれば良いですか？

サンプルコードは以下のサイトのものを参考にしています。
http://www.pori2.net/js/timer/6.html

#### 追記 2017/12/21

アドバイス有難う御座います下のように書き換えてみたのですが音がなりませんでした。
どこかおかしいですか？

```
<script>
var timer1; //タイマーを格納する変数（タイマーID）の宣言

//カウントダウン関数を1000ミリ秒毎に呼び出す関数
function cntStart()
{
  document.timer.elements[2].disabled=true;
  timer1=setInterval("countDown()",1000);
}

//タイマー停止関数
function cntStop()
{
  document.timer.elements[2].disabled=false;
  clearInterval(timer1);
}

//カウントダウン関数
function countDown()
{
  var min=document.timer.elements[0].value;
  var sec=document.timer.elements[1].value;

  if( (min=="") && (sec=="") )
  {
    alert("時刻を設定してください！");
    reSet();
  }
  else
  {
    if (min=="") min=0;
    min=parseInt(min);

    if (sec=="") sec=0;
    sec=parseInt(sec);

    tmWrite(min*60+sec-1);
  }
}

//残り時間を書き出す関数
function tmWrite(int)
{
  int=parseInt(int);

  if (int<=0)
  {
    reSet();
    new Audio("hoge.mp3");
    play();
  }
    else
  {
    //残り分数はintを60で割って切り捨てる
    document.timer.elements[0].value=Math.floor(int/60);
    //残り秒数はintを60で割った余り
    document.timer.elements[1].value=int % 60;
  }
}

//フォームを初期状態に戻す（リセット）関数
function reSet()
{
  document.timer.elements[0].value="0";
  document.timer.elements[1].value="0";
  document.timer.elements[2].disabled=false;
  clearInterval(timer1);
}  
</script>
```

Comment: 書き込み内容がおかしくなっちゃいました。

Answer (score 1):

コードは詳しく見ないと読めない方なのですが、ざっと見てtmWrite関数の中のif文にある`alert("時間です!");`を音を鳴らすコードにしては?
鳴らせる音ファイルの拡張子はmp3、wavです。
簡単にできる方法だと

```
new Audio("パス");
play();
```

になります。
play()以外だと、stop()で止めたり、loop()でループさせたりできます。
loop関数の引数に数字を入れると指定回数だけループ。入れないとエンドレスループ。
play()すると音/音楽が終わったら自動的に停止します。
あまり凝ったことはできません。
http://webos-goodies.jp/archives/50855398.html

そして、私は使っていませんが少し凝ったことができる方法。
リンクだけ掲載しておきます。
https://syncer.jp/html5-javascript-hello-button

mp3が再生できるブラウザは2010~2014年からのブラウザです。wavや他について知りたければ
https://caniuse.com/#
を参考に。他の機能なども調べられます。(私の記憶では)